# Log Off multiple Idle users

Tags: powershell

```
$idle_timout = New-TimeSpan -minutes 1
Add-Type @'
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace PInvoke.Win32 {

    public static class UserInput {

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=false)]
        private static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct LASTINPUTINFO {
            public uint cbSize;
            public int dwTime;
        }

        public static DateTime LastInput {
            get {
                DateTime bootTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMilliseconds(-Environment.TickCount);
                DateTime lastInput = bootTime.AddMilliseconds(LastInputTicks);
                return lastInput;
            }
        }

        public static TimeSpan IdleTime {
            get {
                return DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(LastInput);
            }
        }

        public static int LastInputTicks {
            get {
                LASTINPUTINFO lii = new LASTINPUTINFO();
                lii.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LASTINPUTINFO));
                GetLastInputInfo(ref lii);
                return lii.dwTime;
            }
        }
    }
}
'@

$userId = (Get-Process -PID $pid).SessionID
echo $userID
$loggedOff = 0

foreach ($user in $userid){
   do
{
    $idle_time = [PInvoke.Win32.UserInput]::IdleTime

    if (($loggedOff -eq 0) -And ($idle_time -gt $idle_timout))
    {
        logoff $user

        $loggedOff = 1
    }

    if ($idle_time -lt $idle_timout)
    {
        $loggedOff = 0
    }
}
while (1 -eq 1)
 
}
```

What I am trying to do its log off all users in our conference rooms after a given idle time. What I am trying to do is find all session id's and log off all active sessions. I am not worried about losing work as these are conference room computers. The problem I have is that I can get the session id for the current logged in user but not for all the users logged in. If anyone has any insight it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If anyone has this same problem you can find the script I created here and I paired this with a scheduled to run at any logon event. Logs off the other user so you will only have one user logged in at a time to conference room pc's even if someone forgets. https://github.com/NebulaCyberSolutions/PowershellScripts/blob/master/logoffdual.ps1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here are some options that may be of use

powershell way

```
$computer = 'localhost'
$owners = @{}
Get-WmiObject win32_process -ComputerName $computer -Filter 'name = "explorer.exe"' | % {$owners[$_.handle] = $_.getowner().user}
Get-Process -ComputerName $computer explorer | % {$owners[$_.id.tostring()]}
```

or these

```
$server = 'localhost'

(quser /server:$server) -replace '\s{2,}', ',' | ConvertFrom-Csv

# IDENTICAL
query session /server:$server
qwinsta /server:$server

# IDENTICAL
query user /server:$server
quser /server:$server

qprocess explorer.exe /server:$server
```

Answer (score 2):

you can better do it with remote desktop session host configuration idle time limit to your desired time.
[image]

Comment: Thank you i appreciate the response

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Anthony Stringer's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38665658/45375):

To get an array of all session names associated with *users*:

```
$userSessionNames = query user | Select-Object -Skip 1 |  % { (-split $_)[2] }
```

(`(Get-Process).SessionId | Sort-Object -Unique` would give you all distinct session IDs, but that would include sessions not associated with *users*. That said, if non-user sessions - such as `0` for `services` and `65537` for `rdp-tcp` - are *all* well-known, they could be filtered out.)

Note, however, that your `foreach ($user in $userid)` loop (where `$user` really refers to a user *session*):

- Runs in a *tight loop*, as it runs continuously without yielding CPU time.
- Only ever checks the *calling session's* idle time, because "`GetLastInputInfo` does not provide system-wide user input information across all running sessions. Rather, *GetLastInputInfo provides session-specific user input information for only the session that invoked the function.*" - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you! this really helps

Answer (score 0):

The script I used to achieve this can be found here https://github.com/NebulaCyberSolutions/PowershellScripts/blob/master/logoffdual.ps1. I paired this with a scheduled task that ran at any logon event that would auto log off the oldest user logged in. Effectively only allowing one login at a time to conference room pc's